# What should I do? -- short riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

```
First understand that a child now can,
Soar into sky and fly.
To do so is fatiguing, not to the child who is squealing,
With merriment as they enjoy the ride.
```

For the answer above use the bottom two, put them together and you'll know what to do.

Firstly:

```
In her land is where you'll be,
Smack dab in the middle of open sea.
Mates down where are pretty gung ho,
Don't check above, don'chya know?
```

Secondly:

```
When walking through woods it's good to do this,
Off with their heads yells the queen but she'll miss.
Looks can be deceiving, a docile air,
But get too close and they'll snap at your hair.
```

Comment: `Mates down where` is deliberate or should be `Mates down there`?

Comment: Where is deliberate :)

Comment: Does this require much specific knowledge of e.g. books/movies?

Comment: Doesn't refer to any specific knowlege of the entertainment industry. Some slight geography perhaps, but it's general knowledge that 99.99% of people should be familiar with.

Comment: The answers to the bottom two that is. It might be confusing to some to put those two words together. The answer to the first or a slight variation of it, a person would probably only know it if they had it done to them as a child or have children /close to a family with young kids to do it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should **[under-duck](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=under-duck)** when giving a child a push on a **swing**.

because... (1)

> The answer to the first is 'swing'.

(2)

> The second answer is 'under'. The clues point to 'Australia' or as they say, 'Down Under'

(3)

> The third answer is 'duck'. The clues point to ducking in the woods, when someone is trying to chop off your head, or the animal.

Comment: You are correct about 2 and 3. Put them together and that's the answer for 1! :D

Comment: I'm confused - my first line is incorrect?

Comment: Oh.  I should have gotten this one.  My dad often did this to my nieces.  I have done this myself.  But Paige is using "duck" as a clue for something else.  (I never heard it called this, though.) Hmmm . . . A hint, (I think!) In an old riddle, it's related to a camel or an elephant. (But @PaigeIsn't the answer complete if you respnod to "In her land is where you'll be?")

Comment: eedrah, the answer to the first is the 2nd and 3rd put together. Got the right words, wrong order. Look it up and you'll see what I mean. @Rob ?

Comment: Ok, changed order and added a link. I think the confusion was because where I'm from we don't have a verb for this action specifically - we just use the verb+preposition phrase, hence the different order of words.

Comment: Really?  OK.  I was picturing someone swinging a child without the swing set (basically, **you** are the swing set, by bending over and letting the baby ride on your hands as the he swings back and forth between your legs.  This is fatiguing in a way a playground swing set really isn't.) I also thought you were going for "down" with the mention of a duck.  Calling this type of swinging a child "down-under" makes sense. Obviously, I was waaaay off . . .

Comment: It's okay @Rob the riddle was surely confusing for those unused to the term or action. Nicely done eedrah! I'm happy that you still got it anyways!

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to...

be prepared to give the little girl in the swing another push when she comes back down from her imaginary trip atop the mast of a tall ship at sea, or from a flight above the tops of the trees in a forest.  Also be prepared to duck if she kicks her heels back when you are trying to give her another push.

Comment: close ;P looking for a word though